# how to create a multiple value select in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react and I would like to create a `select` like in the image below,
[image]

I know how to create a normal `select`.

```
<select >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

But I don't how to create `select` that reads the values from an object inside `this.state` that is structured as:

```
state: { "first_one": "All accounts", "second_one": "second property", "third_one": "All Web Site Data"}
```

I want to show the values in the form of that Select. On Clicking the Select, I will open a Modal and I don't need the dropdown to be shown. I don't how to make it. Is there any libraries in `reactJS` to achieve this. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: You should post your code so we can understand better what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @ Ladi Adenusi, Sorry for that, I don't know how to `code` for that. I haven't used this type of `Select` before. I have just used a normal `select` to achieve my needs. Can u provide me some `ideas` to build that type of `Select`....When the `Select` gets clicked, I will open a `Modal` and make it up and I don't need a `dropdown` to be shown.

Comment: So you are basically trying to create a custom select field. Google how to create a custom styled select field ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.
Essentially you hold all your options in the state as you mentioned already, and assign to each one of them a value and the name you want it to be shown. The state `activeItem` holds the current state of the select and is updated through the `onChange` event.

````
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    activeItem: '',
        items: [
        {
        value: "allAccounts",
         name: "All accounts"
        },
        {
        value: "secondProperty",
         name: "Second Property"
        },
        {
        value: "allWebsites",
         name: "All Web Site Data"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  this.setState({activeItem: this.state.items[0].value})
  }

  render() {
  const {items, activeItem } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => this.setState({activeItem: e.target.value})}>
        {items.length && items.map((item, index) => {
                return <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.name}</option>;    
        })}
        </select>
        <div>Active Item: {activeItem}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))

```
````